# Can't find a way to get one of my pictures to stay on screen when my mouse click is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm trying to get an image to stay on screen when my left click is pressed. I've been mostly following the Sentdex videos on youtube for info on how to draw the buttons etc, so if its a bit messy, its because i'm pretty new to pygame! The aim of this game is to be a First Person Shooter, but recently found out that's virtually impossible with python :( So im just carrying on with this project to see where else it could go. Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
import time
import pygame
from tkinter import *
#import pyautogui

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
pygame.init()

display_width = 1200
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)

hgrey = (77,197,179)
hlight_grey = (255,102,106)
grey = (68,187,169)
light_grey = (247,94,98)

pygame.mixer.music.load('music/privia_the_begining.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

counter = 0

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Privia 1.0')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameIcon = pygame.image.load('pics/priviaicon.png')
bannerIcon = pygame.image.load('pics/priviabanner.png')
backgroundMenu = pygame.image.load('pics/bgm.png')
backgroundGameType = pygame.image.load('pics/bgmws.png')

pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

def text_objects(text, font):
  textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
  return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def messeage_display(text):
  largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
  TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
  TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
  gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

  pygame.display.update()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
    pygame.mixer.stop()

def main_menu():
  intro = True

  while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          quit()

    gameDisplay.blit(backgroundMenu, [0, 0])

    gameDisplay.blit(bannerIcon,(300,4))

    button("SinglePlayer",430,260,350,100,grey,hgrey,game_type)
    button("Quit",507,400,200,50,light_grey,hlight_grey,quitgame)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

def game_type():
  gameDisplay.blit(backgroundGameType, [0, 0])
  print("working")

main_menu()
```

Comment: Which picture isn't staying?

Comment: backgroundGameType = pygame.image.load('pics/bgmws.png')

Comment: gameDisplay.blit(backgroundGameType, [0, 0])

Comment: Unfortunately I can't run your code because I don't have all those image files. Could you explain in more detail exactly what you meant by "an image to stay on screen when my left click is pressed"? Do you mean it's normally there and goes away when you click and release, or do you mean it was there, but after a click+release it disappears?

Comment: So when i start up the file, it comes up with a window and and two images and some buttons. (main_menu). Then i can click the quit button, and itll click, whereas when i click the singleplayer button, it should display another image, but only does display that image until i stop click left click. it won't stay on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `backgroundGameType` image isn't staying on the screen because the code only displays (blits) it to screen when the mouse is held down within the region defined for the button.

If you want it say on the screen, one way would be to set a flag that is checked every iteration of in the main event processing loop (`while intro:`) that tracks whether or not to also display it even when the mouse is no longer in that region.

Below is your code modified to do this. Note I have commented out parts of it that have nothing to with the problem — something you should have done before posting your code (or better yet, have removed completely). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

An new global flag variable has been added named `game_mode_selected` and initialized to `False`, and its value is checked each iteration of the main loop. As long as it does not have a "truthy" value, a call is made to display the `"SinglePlayer"` button and check the state of the mouse. When the mouse is clicked within the region defined for it, and the associated `action` function, `game_type()` gets called, the value of this global flag gets changed to "remember" it happened.

Since I assume at that point you no longer wish to have the `"SinglePlayer"` button displayed, I also added a `gameDisplay.fill(black)` call to the beginning of the main loop. Without it the button will continue to be visible even though it not longer does anything.

```
import time
import pygame
from tkinter import *
#import pyautogui

#pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
pygame.init()

display_width = 1200
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)

hgrey = (77,197,179)
hlight_grey = (255,102,106)
grey = (68,187,169)
light_grey = (247,94,98)

#pygame.mixer.music.load('music/privia_the_begining.mp3')
#pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

counter = 0

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Privia 1.0')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#gameIcon = pygame.image.load('pics/priviaicon.png')
#bannerIcon = pygame.image.load('pics/priviabanner.png')
backgroundMenu = pygame.image.load('pics/bgm.png')
backgroundGameType = pygame.image.load('pics/bgmws.png')

#pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

def text_objects(text, font):
  textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
  return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def messeage_display(text):
  largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
  TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
  TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
  gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

  pygame.display.update()

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if (x+w > mouse[0] > x) and (y + h > mouse[1] > y):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
#    pygame.mixer.stop()

game_mode_selected = False  # New global variable

def main_menu():
  global game_mode_selected
  game_mode_selected = False
  intro = True

  while intro:
    gameDisplay.fill(black)  # Added.

    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          quit()

    gameDisplay.blit(backgroundMenu, [0, 0])

#    gameDisplay.blit(bannerIcon,(300,4))

    if not game_mode_selected:
        button("SinglePlayer", 430,260, 350,100, grey, hgrey, game_type)
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(backgroundGameType, [0, 0])

    button("Quit", 507,400, 200,50, light_grey, hlight_grey, quitgame)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

def game_type():
  global game_mode_selected
  game_mode_selected = True  # Change global because button was clicked.

  gameDisplay.blit(backgroundGameType, [0, 0])
  print("working")

main_menu()
```